# jQuery - Nested vs. unnested transition and animation event handlers/listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a set of code which runs every time a certain ajax call happens.

To do this I use the below snippet (it errors as I think there is no html or css, but that's okay as I am just trying to show my code):

```js
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  if ($('.spinner').length < 1) { //as there is no ajaxStop, this makes sure there is not already a spinner
    $('body').prepend('<div class="spinner" title="Spinner stuck? Click to remove!"></div>');
  }
  $('body div').not('.spinner').css('opacity', '0.5'); //this is potentially unnecessary
});

//the rest of the ajax call is not included - just the .done()
.done(function(xhr) {
  $('body div').not('.spinner').css('opacity', '0');
  $('body').one('transitionend', function(e) {
    $('body div').not('.spinner').remove();
    $('body').append(xhr);
    $('body div').not('.spinner').css('opacity', '0.1');
    $('body').one('transitionend', function(e) {
      $('body div').css('opacity', '1');
      $('.spinner').remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I nest `.one('transitionend')`s, which I am trying to figure out if it is correct or not (as a note: that code is used to handle log-in and log-out ajax call responses. It works *most of the time* for my login ajax call but is currently not working for the logout ajax call - I don't think it's registering the end `$('body div').not('.spinner').css('opacity', '0.1');`'s transition, as that is where it freezes).

I have thrown together [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4lackof/t9Lomf3w/1/). It is just to test nested vs. unnested event handlers.

They both (nested and unnested) seem to work the same (early on it would freeze up if you click one of them too many times - it happened on both nested and unnested - but that seems to be fixed after I added the log bit - `$('#log span').text($('#div1').text());`, etc.).

Here is that jsfiddle in a snippet:

```js
var newCss = {
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  width: '25%',
  color: 'white'
};
var disabled = false;
$(document).on('click', '#div1', function(e) {
  if (disabled) return;
  notNested($(this));
});

$(document).on('click', '#div8', function(e) {
  if (disabled) return;
  nested($(this));
});

function notNested($this) {
  disabled = true;
  $this.css(newCss);
  $('#log span').text($('#div1').text());
  $('#div1').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('#div2').css(newCss);
    $('#log span').text($('#div2').text());
  });
  $('#div2').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('#div3').css(newCss);
    $('#log span').text($('#div3').text());
  });
  $('#div3').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('#div4').css(newCss);
    $('#log span').text($('#div4').text());
  });
  $('#div4').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('#div5').css(newCss);
    $('#log span').text($('#div5').text());
  });
  $('#div5').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('#div6').css(newCss);
    $('#log span').text($('#div6').text());
  });
  $('#div6').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('#div7').css(newCss);
    $('#log span').text($('#div7').text());
  });
  $('#div7').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('div').removeAttr('style');
    $('#log span').text('');
    disabled = false;
  });
}

function nested($this) {
  disabled = true;
  $this.css(newCss);
  $('#log span').text($('#div8').text());
  $('#div8').one('transitionend', function() {
    $('#div9').css(newCss);
    $('#log span').text($('#div9').text());
    $('#div9').one('transitionend', function() {
      $('#div10').css(newCss);
      $('#log span').text($('#div10').text());
      $('#div10').one('transitionend', function() {
        $('#div11').css(newCss);
        $('#log span').text($('#div11').text());
        $('#div11').one('transitionend', function() {
          $('#div12').css(newCss);
          $('#log span').text($('#div12').text());
          $('#div12').one('transitionend', function() {
            $('#div13').css(newCss);
            $('#log span').text($('#div13').text());
            $('#div13').one('transitionend', function() {
              $('#div14').css(newCss);
              $('#log span').text($('#div14').text());
              $('#div14').one('transitionend', function() {
                $('#log span').text('');
                $('div').removeAttr('style');
                disabled = false;
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* Can't remember if flex-start is default anyways*/
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
div > div {
  border: 4px dotted red;
  transition: .25s;
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 16px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
  <div id="div4">4</div>
  <div id="div5">5</div>
  <div id="div6">6</div>
  <div id="div7">7</div>
</div>
<div id="log">We got to: <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="div8">8</div>
  <div id="div9">9</div>
  <div id="div10">10</div>
  <div id="div11">11</div>
  <div id="div12">12</div>
  <div id="div13">13</div>
  <div id="div14">14</div>
</div>
```

> So thus, I am trying to figure out, which one is the better to use? Which causes less problems for the code/browser? etc. **Is there a better way to control code which depends on transitions (or animations for that matter) to be in a certain state?** *(Looking for a matter of fact answer, not opinions, [TUVM](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20TUVM))*

I have tried researching jQuery's [.queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [.delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/), but could not get either to work in my scenario (probably I was using them wrong). Maybe it is another possibility? I also know `setTimeout()` is a possibility, but to keep it synchronous you would need to nest the elements after it (and also `.one('transitionend')` seems to work *in **most** cases* whether you nest then or not...)

### UPDATE:

Based on the following comment left on this question:

> Some minor pointers on your code, don't do css in Jquery but append/prepend classes with the opacity value. Use variables instead of going through the DOM with every selector. – [Jan_dh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4170742/jan-dh)

I have updated the jsfiddle to change the classes instead of changing the CSS directly. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4lackof/t9Lomf3w/1/) is the link (also, the jsfiddle link above was updated).

Although, I don't duplicate what is mean by:

> Use variables instead of going through the DOM with every selector.

If this could possibly be an answer to my question, maybe someone who does understand what he means can elaborate below?

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com. It's a better place to discuss making working code better, than stackoverflow which is geared towards making code work.

Comment: Nested is the only choice for infinite animations.

Comment: @Goose: The question is fine here.

Comment: @4lackof: I see that your bounty description is "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources."  Are you expecting a reference to an MDN or W3C document?  Normally their expertise is to tell you how the tools work, and then let you decide how to use them.

Comment: Some minor pointers on your code, don't do css in Jquery but append/prepend classes with the opacity value. Use variables instead of going through the DOM with every selector.

Comment: @RobertHarvey tku. I guess I am looking for a stable way to accomplish this, as the way I show above seems a bit hacky, and is quite finicky in how it works (sometimes errs, etc.). Despite my googling, this is the only way I could find how to do it (although that is probably from an in-expertise of "Google-search-skillz"). Thus I am coming here to get answers, but am looking for more official answers (not really opinions).

Comment: @Jan_dh those are some good pointers, I'll work in implementing them, but will still need to work on a solution for triggering them at the correct moment

Comment: There's no such thing as "official."  There are only things that people have tried which worked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you're right, "official" is a misnomer. I am totally for an answer in terms of what will _work_ (as that is all that matters in the end, no?). Currently, my code is glitchy (i.e. sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't) and pretty hacky. so thus I am asking if what I am doing is correct. It is the only workable (or, rather, more workable than others) solution I have found at this current moment in time, but I need something which _works_ even better (in alignment with my question above). Tku

Comment: _"I have updated the jsfiddle to change the classes instead of changing the CSS directly. Here is the link (also, the jsfiddle link above was updated)."_ Adding and removing `className` is equivalent to calling `.css()`, that is calling a function for each element, as the elements are referenced by `id`; though you did not update `javascript` regarding second part of suggestion, e.g., storing reference to element in variables rather than calling `jQuery()` at each selection of element

Comment: @guest271314 thank you. yes, I did not update that part of the JS  as you can see from what I wrote after the part you quote _"Although, I don't duplicate what is mean by: 'Use variables instead of going through the DOM with every selector.'"_ maybe you can shed some light on what it means? (of course, as long as it would keep us on topic in regards to the question so as to be in accordance with stack overflow guild-lines) Tks

Comment: @4lackof _"maybe you can shed some light on what it means?"_ Believe suggestion means calling [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) as few times as possible by creating a variable which references single element or collection of elements, for example, `log`, `divs`, `col1`, `col2` at Answer define variables referencing single and multiple elements using one call to `$()` for each reference to single or collection of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.queue()`, `$.map()`; `.one("transitionend")` attached to current transitioning element with handler set to `next` to call next function in queue when current element `transition` completes; single event handler for each column of elements by utilizing `.slice()` to split all elements where element `id` begins with `"div"` into two or more elements of an array; pass the array to event handler as `event.data`; filter specific column with `$.grep()`, `.filter()`; set the collection of elements `.data(/* name */)` to `true` or `false` to prevent default action of transition effect when elements are currently being transitioned in queue at `click` of element when transition is in progress; `.promise()`, `.then()` to perform task when current queue is complete

```js
var newCss = {
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  width: "25%",
  color: "white"
}
// define `log` variable as `"#log span"`
, log = $("#log span")
// define `divs` variable as all elements where `id` begins with`` "div"
, divs = $("[id^=div]")
// define `col1` variable as `divs` at indexes `0` through `7`
, col1 = divs.slice(0, 7)
// define `col2` variable as `divs` at indexes `7` through `div.length`
, col2 = divs.slice(7, divs.length);

function queueColumn(col, name) {
  // set current collection of elements `.data("active")` to `true`
  return col.data("active", true)
    // set a queue name with `name`, call `$.map()` on current collection
    .queue(name, $.map(col, function(div) {
     // return a function at queue `name` for each element in collection
      return function(next) {
        // set `log` text
        log.text(
          // pass reference of `next` function in queue `name`
          // as handler for `transitionend` event of current element;
          // call `next` function in queue `name`
          // at `transitionend` event of element
          $(div).one("transitionend", next).css(newCss).text()
        )
      }
    // call first function in queue;
    // when all function in queue `name` complete,
    // return queue `name` jQuery promise object
    })).dequeue(name).promise(name)
}
// handle `click` event at `#div1`, `#div8` elements
function handleQueue(e) {
  // define `curr` variable;
  // filter array containing `col1`, `col2` collections
  // to match collection containing `#div1` or `#div8`     
  var curr = $.grep(e.data, function(col) {
    return col.filter(e.target).length
  }).pop();
  // create `name` for queue
  var name = `col${$.inArray(curr, e.data) + 1}-${$.now()}`;
  // check if `curr` `.data("active")` is `undefined` 
  // at first click of element, if true, 
  // set `curr` `.data("active")` to `false` 
  if (curr.data("active") === undefined) {
    curr.data("active", false);
  }
  if (curr.data("name") === undefined) {
    curr.data("name", name);
  }
  console.log(`queue ${curr.data("name")} is active:`
             , `${!curr.queue(name).length 
                  || curr.data("active")}`);
  // define `inprogress` as `curr.data().active`
  var inprogress = curr.data().active;
  // check if `inprogress` is `false`, if true, call call `queueColumn`
  // with `curr`, `name` as parameters
  // if `#div1` or `#div8` element are clicked during 
  // during queue, while `inprogress` is `true`,
  // return `false` from event handler to prevent
  // multiple queues to be set at `curr` at same time
  return !inprogress
         ? queueColumn(curr, name)
           // do stuff when current queue `name` completes
           // calling all functions in queue array
           .then(function() {
             console.log(`${this.data("name")} queue complete`);
             // remove element `style`, reset `.data()`
             this.removeAttr("style")
             .data({"active": false, "name": void 0});        
            }) 
           // else return `false` 
         : inprogress
}
// at `click` of `#div1`, `#div8`, call `handleQueue`,
// pass array containing `col1`, `col2` as `event.data`
$("#div1, #div8").click([col1, col2], handleQueue);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* Can't remember if flex-start is default anyways*/
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}
div > div {
  border: 4px dotted red;
  transition: .25s;
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 16px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <div id="div1">1</div>
  <div id="div2">2</div>
  <div id="div3">3</div>
  <div id="div4">4</div>
  <div id="div5">5</div>
  <div id="div6">6</div>
  <div id="div7">7</div>
</div>
<div id="log">We got to: <span></span>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="div8">8</div>
  <div id="div9">9</div>
  <div id="div10">10</div>
  <div id="div11">11</div>
  <div id="div12">12</div>
  <div id="div13">13</div>
  <div id="div14">14</div>
</div>
```

Comment: some interesting code. I think this might be a solution; however, I am trying to understand it (so that I can be able to use it for my code - the jsfiddle is just an example). While I am looking the jquery API site on the different functions you use to understand those, are you able to add comments? Tku